# user defined signals sigusr1 and sigusr2

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc

I have am building a simple software in which there are multiple processes communicating with each other using the user defined signals SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2.

I am just curious to know what happens in a scenario like what I am describing below.

"Process-1 did send sigusr1 to process-2 using kill command and the process-2 is executing the signal-handler doing some computation. Even before process-2 completed the execution of signal handler process-1 sends sigusr1 again to process-2. What would happen. I am unable to get a proper answer for this one. I think of two possible scenarios.

1. The handler being executed currently gets interrupted ? or
2. The second signal would be ignored by process-2.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing signals take some time and if you send too much at a time, some could get ignored.

What you could do is send a response signal to the other process , basically saying :

> Hey, I got your signal, send me the next one I'm ready

This way, no signal would get ignored and your program will get much faster with less to no errors.

If you want a cheap solution, just use `usleep()` and a small value (depend on your hardware actually)

Here is an example where an ascii message is sent to another process using signals :

> Client - Sending part

```
void        decimal_conversion(char ascii, int power, int pid)
{
  if (power > 0)
    decimal_conversion(ascii / 2, power - 1, pid);
  if ((ascii % 2) == 1)
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
  else
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
  usleep(1);
}

void        ascii_to_binary(char *str, int pid)
{
  int       i;

  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
      decimal_conversion(str[i], 7, pid);
      i += 1;
    }
}
```

> Server

```
void        sighandler(int signum)
{
  static int    ascii = 0;
  static int    power = 0;

  if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    ascii += 1 << (7 - power);
  if ((power += 1) == 8)
    {
      putchar(ascii);
      power = 0;
      ascii = 0;
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
  signal(SIGUSR1, sighandler);
  signal(SIGUSR2, sighandler);
  while (42);
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I built a program like yours month ago where the goal was to send text from one process to another using signals. From what I experienced, if you dont wait for the process-2 to complete its computation, the signal sent by process-1 will be ignored by the second process and your message / data will be lost.

For this not to happen I would suggest you to send a signal back from process-2 to tell process-1 that the computation is over and it can send another message.

Comment: Why not using pipe to send text ?

Comment: It was a project for School, I know that's not the most efficient way to do it but using signals was mandatory and nothing else was allowed.